# Table query in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, sqlite, internationalization, diacritics

I have a tableview (linked to a database) and a search bar. When I type something in the search bar, I do a quick search in the database and display the results as I type.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name LIKE '%NAME%'
```

Everything works fine as long as I use only ASCII characters. What I want is to type ASCII characters and to match their equivalent with diacritics. For instance, if I type "Alizee" I would expect it to match "Alizée".

Is there a way to do make the query locale-insensitive? I've red about the COLLATE option in SQL, but there seems to be of no use with SQLite.I've also red that iPhone SDK 3.0 has "Localized collation" but I was unable to find any documentation about what this means...

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options for solving this:

1. Replacing all accented chars in the
   query before executing it, e.g.

   > "Psychédélices" => "Psychedelices"
   >   "À contre-courant" => "A contre-courant"
   >   "Tempête" => "Tempete"
   >   etc.

   but this only works for the input so
   you must not have accented chars in
   the database itself. Simple solution but
   far from perfect.
2. Using a 3rd party library, namely ICU (links below). Not sure if it's the best choice for iPhone though.
3. Writing one or more custom C functions that will do the comparison. More in the links below.

A few posts here on StackOverflow that discuss the various options:
[How to sort text in sqlite3 with specified locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611459/how-to-sort-text-in-sqlite3-with-specified-locale)
[Case-insensitive UTF-8 string collation for SQLite (C/C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181037/case-insensitive-utf-8-string-collation-for-sqlite-c-c)
[How to implement the accent/diacritic insensitive search in Sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779853/how-to-implement-the-accent-diacritic-insensitive-search-in-sqlite)

Also a couple of external links:
[SQLite and native UNICODE LIKE support in C/C++](http://ioannis.mpsounds.net/blog/2007/12/19/sqlite-native-unicode-like-support/)
[sqlite case and accent insensitive searches](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg42923.html)

Comment: Thanks, I decided to replace all accented chars. By the way, I like your examples. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about SQL, but I think you can definitely use the `NSDiacriticInsensitivePredicateOption` to compare in-memory NSStrings.

An example would be an NSArray full of the strings you're searching over. You could just iterate over the array comparing strings using the `NSDiacriticInsensitivePredicateOption` as your comparison option and displaying the successful matches.

Comment: Thanks, but my table has up to 50.000 rows so in-memory searching is not an option, unfortunately.